# ERROR anaconda_api.is_vscode_available:871

Tags: anaconda, spyder

I'm working on linux mint. When I'm trying to run anaconda-navigator, the following error appears

```
ERROR anaconda_api.is_vscode_available:871
```

Beside that and in the period that following the appearance of this error anaconda has some strange behavior, for example: when i'm trying to lunch spyder it want lunch... So please anyone can help?

Thanks

Comment: I get this error too, even after "conda update anaconda-navigator". But I can still launch Spyder.

Comment: I also tried "conda update conda". Now my applications have disappeared in the navigator... Signed into anaconda cloud and "conda update spyder". Ah they're back now.

Comment: Though I still get the error you reported.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do some simple work first and adapt to the situation and do the following:

```
conda install -f launcher
conda install -f node-webkit
conda update -n base conda
conda update conda
conda update anaconda
```

This is important After these steps, launch Anakonda navigator and click yes  on the upgrade button and close the anaconda to let it upgrade.

At last  open terminal and do:

```
jupyter notebook
```

And again:

```
jupyter notebook
jupyter notebook --allow-root
```

Reboot and here we go.